# Get data from JSON to table view

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, parsing

I have a JSON data from http://vmg.hdvietpro.com/ztv/home . I want to get text1,thumbnailImage value in this JSON after clicking getData button to get text1,thumbnailImage(NSString) values from JSON to table view. This is my code and after click button nothing happen. Thanks for help.

```
@interface ViewController ()
{
    NSMutableData *webData;
    NSURLConnection *connection;
    NSMutableArray *moviesArray;

}
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [[self myTableView]setDelegate:self];
     [[self myTableView]setDataSource:self];
    moviesArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{
    [webData setLength:0];
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{
    [webData appendData:data];
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"Fail");
}
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
    NSDictionary *allDataDictionary=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webData options:0 error:nil];
    NSDictionary *response=[allDataDictionary objectForKey:@"response"];
    NSDictionary *hotProgram=[response objectForKey:@"hot_program"];
                                 NSArray *itemPageHot=[hotProgram objectForKey:@"page"];
    for (NSDictionary*dic  in itemPageHot) {
        NSString *text1=[dic objectForKey:@"text1"];
        [moviesArray addObject:text1];


    }
    [[self myTableView]reloadData];
}
- (IBAction)getData:(id)sender {
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://vmg.hdvietpro.com/ztv/home"];
    NSURLRequest *request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    if(connection){
        webData =[[NSMutableData alloc]init];
        NSLog(@"ket noi thanh cong");
    }
}
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [moviesArray count];
}
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString*CellIndentifier=@"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIndentifier];

    if(!cell){
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIndentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text=[moviesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: i get the data in connectionDidFinishLoading method . is that true?

Comment: You're right - I didn't even see you copied that delegate in. Can you put a debug in to see if you're populating moviesArray?

Comment: NSLog each bit of JSON as you unravel it -- allDataDictionary, response, hotProgram, itemPageHot, dic, text1.

Answer (score 0):

You're not traversing the dictionary correctly. The key `page` is a child of key `itemPage` so this should work

`NSArray *itemPageHot = [[hotProgram objectForKey:@"itemPage"] objectForKey:@"page"];`

I'd recommend downloading a JSON inspector for issues like this. VisualJSON in the app store is what I use.

Comment: Plain old NSLog does a fine job of dumping deserialized JSON, if you know how to translate the few differences.

Comment: That's good to know but it's nice to have the collapsable trees especially if you're dealing with large data.